# Call an object using a function in R

Tags: r

I have R objects:

```
    "debt_30_06_2010" "debt_30_06_2011" "debt_30_06_2012" ...
```

and need to call them using a function:

```
    paste0("debt_",date) ## "date" being another object
```

The problem is that when I assign the call to another object it takes only the name not the content:

```
    debt_a <- paste0("endeud_", date1)
    > debt_a
    [1] "debt_30_06_2014"
```

I've tried to use the function "assign" without success:

```
    assign("debt_a", paste0("debt_", date))
    > debt_a
    [1] "debt_30_06_2014"
```

I would like to know there is any method to achieve this task.

Comment: You can use `mget` ie. `mget(paste0('debt_", date))` to get the value.  A reproducible example would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `get` to get the value of the object.  If there are multiple objects, use `mget`.  For example, here I am `assign`ing 'debt_a' with the value of 'debt_30_06_2010'

```
 assign('debt_a', get(paste0('debt_', date[1])))
 debt_a
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

`mget` returns a `list`.  So if we are assigning 'debt_a' to multiple objects,

```
 assign('debt_a', mget(paste0('debt_', date)))
 debt_a
 #$debt_30_06_2010
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5

 #$debt_30_06_2011
 #[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

#### data

```
debt_30_06_2010 <- 1:5
debt_30_06_2011 <- 6:10
date <- c('30_06_2010', '30_06_2011')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I suspect that your objects are names of functions, and that you want to construct these names as characters to use the functions. If this is the case, this example might help:

```
myfun <- function(x){sin(x)**2}
mychar <- paste0("my", "fun")
eval(call(mychar, x = pi / 4))
#[1] 0.5
#> identical(eval(call(mychar, x = pi / 4)), myfun(pi / 4))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I would be thankful if you could post a short comment to let me know if this related to what you intended to achieve. To avoid confusion I would like to remove my answer if it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: The OP's description is `I have R objects: ... and need to call them using a function:`.  I think he wants to get the value of the stored object instead of calling something like you mentioned

Comment: It is exactly the part with "I need to call them" which made me think that those might be more than just a string of characters, but I'm really unsure.

Comment: Upon reconsideration, I think that you're right @akrun. Your answer probably provides the desired solution. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: You can keep the answer until the OP responds.  It can be either way. Sometimes, people post questions with some key words that can be confusing.